# How many solutions are there – inclusion-exclusion combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=10$
when

$x_1+x_2>0$ ,$x_2+x_3>0$, $x_3+x_4>0$
my Universe is $U= {n+k-1\choose k-1} ={10+4-1\choose 4-1}$

I thought I will get new variable $x_i+x_j=y_i+y_j+1$
so the problem is equivalent to:
$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=8$

how can I continue this with the inclusion-exclusion principle?

Generally, I understand the inclusion-exclusion principle, but in this problem somthing confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ denote the set of solutions for $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=10$ where the $x_i$ denote nonnegative integers.

For $i=1,2,3$ let $S_{i,i+1}\subseteq S$ denote the set of solutions that moreover satisfy $x_i+x_{i+1}=0$.

Then to be found is:$$\left|S_{1,2}^{\complement}\cap S_{2,3}^{\complement}\cap S_{3,4}^{\complement}\right|=\left|\left(S_{1,2}\cup S_{2,3}\cup S_{3,4}\right)^{\complement}\right|=\left|S\right|-\left|S_{1,2}\cup S_{2,3}\cup S_{3,4}\right|=$$$$\left|S\right|-\left|S_{1,2}\right|-\left|S_{2,3}\right|-\left|S_{3,4}\right|+\left|S_{1,2}\cap S_{2,3}\right|+\left|S_{1,2}\cap S_{3,4}\right|+\left|S_{2,3}\cap S_{3,4}\right|-\left|S_{1,2}\cap S_{2,3}\cap S_{3,4}\right|$$

---

Is my interpretation of your question correct? And if so then can you take it from here?

Comment: the interpretation looks great , is this $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=8$ equation is also true ?    and if not can you explain why?   and if $S_1,2=1 ? beacuse if $x1+x2=0,$ then $x3+x4=10$

Comment: Is $x_i+x_j=y_i+y_j+1$ demanded for all pairs $(i,j)$ with $i\neq j$? If so then it is demanded in your construction that $x_1+x_3>0$ which is not necessary. Also $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(0,1,0,9)$ is a solution. I cannot decipher the second part of your comment.

Comment: no , the demend is $1+2>0 ,2+3>0, 3+4>0$

Comment: Solution $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(1,1,1,7)$ corresponds with more than one solution for $(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)$. For instance $(1,0,1,6)$ and $(0,1,0,7)$. I think that might spoil your construction.

Comment: @cisco_guy drhab's solution does not involve a change of variables.

Comment: , thank you i got it! , its $U- 31$  alll the $/B_i,i+1 \bigcup $ and $-$  all of the $B_i,i+1  $x_i+x_{i+1}=0$ great !